# Find out signing signature of application that invoked my activity?

Tags: android

If a third party developer invokes one of my activities, is there a way to get the signing signature of the process/application the activity is running in? For example, a third party app invokes one of my activities like so:

```
// ThirdPartyActivity.java
Intent res = new Intent();
String mPackage = "com.me.test";
String mClass = ".MyActivity";
res.setComponent(new ComponentName(mPackage,mPackage+mClass));
startActivity(res);
```

Now my activity gets created in their process space (as I understand). Could I then somehow figure out what the signing signature is of the owning process?:

```
// MyActivity.java
public void onCreate() {
    String signingSignatureOfProcessImRunningIn = ...;
}
```

I'm basically looking to verify that a third party is who they say they are (I know their signing signature before-hand),

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Activities are by default run in the same process only if they belong to the same application.

When apps are installed they get a unique userID and it's components run in a separate processes. You can explicitly define a [`android:process`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#proc) in apps manifest in order to have two apps (with same process name) share one process/JVM (they must also be signed with the same key).

**Update**

You don't need to do this via processes (which does not work anyway). Do this in your activity:

```
String callingPackage = getCallingPackage();
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(callingPackage, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
Signature[] signatures = info.signatures;
```

Comment: This isn't answering the users question

Comment: The OP's premise is that his Activity gets run in another apps process, which he would like to inspect. This does not happen - invoked activity gets started in it's own process. That was my point.

Comment: You're still not addressing the signature issue though, which was his actual question. The process id is orthogonal to the actual question, he/she was just using that as an example.

Comment: I told him that what he tried to do was not the solution. Does that warrant a -1? And by the way I did provide the solution in update.

Comment: Much better. I felt that he was just offering the process as one potential solution for the problem, but he wasn't sure if it would work. You did a good job of dismissing it, but didn't provide anything constructive. Now that you have, I shall retract the -1.

Answer (score -1):

you can get Intent which start your activity. Look here: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29)

I think you can khow what activity sends this Intent

===============================

There may be another way, but the only solution I know of is having Activity A invoke Activity B via startActivityForResult(). Then Activity B can use getCallingActivity() to retrieve Activity A's identity.

Hope, it help you!